# SonarQube 5.4 - StartSonar.bat - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

I am trying to run StartSonar.bat in my machine, facing the below error, it was working previously when I was using 1.7x version of java.

### Error Message

```
Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.08.03 11:27:58 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory H:\MyProjects\Sonar\SonarQube5.4\sonarqube-5.4\temp
2016.08.03 11:27:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\java
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=H:\MyProjects\Sonar\SonarQube5.4\sonarqube-5.4\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\Raghav~1.Ram\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process8222732762711105748properties 
Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
```

And then wrapper stopped.

### Configuration:

java 32bit, java version "1.8.0_92"
OSArchitecture:64-bit

### Things I tried:

I tried changing the size in sonar properties file, but it didn't work.
I tried uninstalling some application in my system

Answer (score 3):

You have not enough available memory on your system, you can either reduce the -Xmx1G parameter to -Xmx256m or increase your available memory by increasing your swap size.

Comment: Also schedule an upgrade to the LTS version (SonarQube 5.6)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried reducing the available memory, but it didn't work. Anyy idea on how to increase the swap size? And also upgrade 5.4 to 5.6 when I am not able to start the sonar itself?

Comment: In your sonar folder, edit the conf/sonar.properties and add the following line.
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx256m -Xms128m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \